# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program

Tags: java

I created new java project in Netbeans:

```
package copyfiles;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class CopyFiles {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```

And I selected:

1. Clean and Build Main Project
2. Run Main Project

I have an error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" (in directory "/Users/xxx/yyy/kopiowanie plików/CopyFiles"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Seems like classpath for Java_home is not set properly. It seems the classpath has set java_home to /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java, but java is not actually available at that location.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you have mis configured where to find the JDK used to run your program as the `java` you are trying to use doesn't exist.

Can you do

```
ls -l /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check whether Java is available at

> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

or not. I don't think it is available. If it is not there and if someone has changed the java folder name, n your Netbeans IDE go to

> Tools-->Java Platform

and click

> Add Platform

and add the Java folder. If you run the program after this, I suppose your program should work.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've got the reason.

It likely to Netbeans cannot support Non-Ascii path.Path part "kopiowanie plików" cannot be accepted in this path "/Users/xxx/yyy/kopiowanie plików/CopyFiles".

So u should move your project into a new folder like "/Users/xxx/yyy/projectABC/CopyFiles".

Sorry for my English. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem. I actually had 2, but fixed the first one. In the process a website suggested setting the "Run as Administrator" in the compatibility settings for "java.exe" in the bin folder. 
I fixed the first problem, but still had this error until I turned off the "Run as Administrator" option.
Now it's working.